# If statement not executing in vue 3 async function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, vuejs3

I'm busy with a client management system project, but I'm having a bit of trouble with my async functions. I do the api calls in a seperate js file APIController\api.js and in the UserForm.vue component I have an async function createUser that is supposed to call two functions ported into the component as props.  The code is as follows:

I have the ref and APIController imported:

```
import { ref } from 'vue';
import APIController from '@\Controllers\api';
```

I have the props imported:

```
props: ["toggleForm", "fetchUsers", "userId"],
```

And finally my setup function with the async function:

```
setup(props){
        const user = ref({});
        const createUser = async () => {
            const success = await APIController.CreateUser(user.value.name, user.value.phone, user.value.address);
            if(success){
                props.fetchUsers();
                props.toggleForm();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the APIController.CreateUser() function for further clarification:

```
CreateUser: (name, phone, address) => {
        if(
            name == "" ||
            phone == "" ||
            address == ""
        ) {
            return false;
        } else {

            fetch(API_BASE + "/users/create", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ name, phone, address })
            }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if(data.success){
                    return data.response.user;
                } else {
                    throw data.response.error;
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                alert(err);
            });
        }
    },
```

The function executes the api call perfectly, but the if statement doesn't execute at all.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `success`? Also, does `APIController.CreateUser();` ever resolve?

Comment: What is the success value?

Comment: We still don't know what is the value of `success`

Comment: Add `console.log(success)` before the `if` statement.

Comment: @VLAZ success is a boolean value and yes, the APIController.CreateUser() does resolve as the data passed to the function is stored in the database.

Comment: @Barmar, I did and the console returns it as 'undefined'

Comment: @BlackBat023 _There you go then_: remember that **`undefined` is not the same thing as `""`** (an empty string). Change your `if` to something like `if( typeof name === 'string' && name.length > 0 && typeof phone === 'string' && phone.length > 0 && typeof address === 'string' && address.length > 0 ) { /* do stuff */ }`. (You can avoid these kinds of problems entirely by using TypeScript btw).

Comment: @Dai this is not the solution. OP jus tdidjtn return anything from the `else` block

Comment: Add `return` before `fetch`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, but I am returning the `data.response.user` in the fetch statement why would I then need to return the whole fetch statement? Just a bit confused by that.

Comment: @BlackBat023 return only works in a function scope. You create a new function in each `then` clause, so it doesn't return from the entire `CreateUser` function.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, Oh I see, so unless I return the whole fetch function I wouldn't have access to the return in the .then function?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to figure it out, but let me just state categorically that I could not have done it without your input.  It occurred to me that the `if(success){ props.toggleForm(); props.fetchUsers();}` conditional needed to read as true before the block executes.  My problem was to get it to read as true as the `console.log(success)` command returned it as undefined.  You guys then got me looking at the api call and I thought, I am expecting it to return true once the bool variable success contains data it gets from the APIController call.  But what if that isn't how it works.  So I made just changed the if conditional in the api call to simply `return true` and that worked.

```
CreateUser: (name, phone, address) => {
        if(
            name == "" ||
            phone == "" ||
            address == ""
        ) {
            return false;
        } else {

            fetch(API_BASE + "/users/create", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ name, phone, address })
            }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if(data.success){
                    alert("User created successfuly");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    throw data.response.error;
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                alert(err);
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks again to everyone for your help and input! This saved me hours of possible stress and headaches ;-).